# Сохранение цвета кнопки после нажатия в балуне яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо что бы после нажатия кнопки, в балуне метки сохранялся измененный цвет после того как балун закрыли и открыли снова. Меток много и балун каждой метки заполняется динамически кнопками с уникальными Id и заранее определенными цветами по классу css. Моя идея заключалась в том, что после нажатия на кнопку, цвет сохраняется в localStorage с учетом уникального Id кнопки, и потом в событии при открытии балуна проверяются Id из html кода балуна и сравниваются с их наличием в localStorage и при совпадении им переназначается цвет.
Так же я подумал что в строке кода `var data = e.get('target').balloon.getData();` мы получаем как раз таки данные с балуна, но непонятно как получить от туда html из balloonContentBody и от туда получить необходимое Id.

Или лучше поменять подход?

Код ниже написан на нескольких языках, но я надеюсь что общий смысл понятен.

```
@: balloonContentBody:
@:'<table class="table" id="@item.Id">'+
                foreach (var p in item.Persons)
                {   
                    if (p.Target != true)
                    {                       
                        nottarget++;
                        @:'<tr class="tr1"><td class="td1"><b id="spec @p.Id">@p.Speciality</b><br><input class="inputs-red" onclick="setColor(event, this.id)"'+
                        @: `id=p"@p.Id" type="button" value="@p.FIO" data-count="1"></input></td></tr>`+ 
                    }
                    else
                    {                                           
                        target++;                        
                        @:'<tr class="tr1"><td class="td1"><b id="spec @p.Id">@p.Speciality</b><br><input class="inputs-green" onclick="setColor(event, this.id)"'+
                        @: `id="p@p.Id" type="button" value="@p.FIO" data-count="0"></input></td></tr>`+ 
                    }
                                  
                }
                @:'</table>',
                @: balloonContentFooter: '',
                @: hintContent: '@item.OrganisationName - <b class="inputs-green">@target</b>, <b class="inputs-red">@nottarget</b>'
                @:  });
                @: myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
                
         myMap.geoObjects.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {                  
         var data = e.get('target').balloon.getData();
       }
```

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, в чём сложность выуживать placemark.properties.get('balloonContentBody') если честно. И почему id нельзя хранить опять же в собственном properties.pointID и брать оттуда в любой момент, например... Может на рабочем примере кода объясните?

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарий, я неправильно пытался получить balloonContentBody в событии. Вместо `e.get('target').balloon.getData('balloonContentBody');` нужно было написать `e.get('target').properties.get('balloonContentBody');`. А id у меня индивидуальные для каждой кнопки в балуне метки и изначально они устанавливаются в html коде, что бы потом можно было сохранять изменение цвета за ними. Поэтому не очень понял часть с хранением id в properties.pointID.

Comment: Если вам удобно обрабатывать ID в текущем формате, можете так и оставить. Это не принципиально. Я имел в виду, что объектам можно прописывать и кастомные параметры в options или properties, чтобы при обработке к ним обращаться напрямую, как к штатным параметрам.